# PHP - LDAP search

Tags: php, ldap-query

I am trying to get all user from the AD group. But have the problem to create correct filter. this is my code.

```
$filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(users=All_K_Users))";  
$attributes = array("name");
    if (!($search = ldap_search($ds, 'dc=edu' , $filter, $attributes))) {
        die("Unable to search ldap server");
    }

    $number_returned = ldap_count_entries($ds,$search);
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);

    echo "The number of entries returned is ". $number_returned."<p>";
```

The result is 0

what I did wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Does the entry you search for have a `users` attribute? Do any entries have the value `All_K_Users` for that attribute? How have you checked this?

Comment: All_K_Users  this is a AD group name. I need to get all users from this  group.

Comment: So if that should be the group name, why are you filtering for `users` attribute to hold that value?

Comment: I used  member like this  $filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(member=All_K_Users))";  but it not working too. This is why I am asking wjhat is wrong in my filter. :)

Comment: I don't know anything about active directory, but I'd guess the group **name** is not stored in an attribute called `users` or `member`. Probably `name` would be the first one I try.

Comment: and memberOf too